# Sublime text 2: how to bind 'comment a line' command for java .properties files

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, properties-file

Maybe title is a little bit sophisticated, but situation is simpler:

In Sublime text 2 for the 'Java Properties' scope (for the files with '*.properties' extension) doesn't work shortcut 'comment a line' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in Win).

So maybe someone knows how to implement this functionality? I've tried, but 'Java Properties' doesn't have separate package and this is confused me.

use case:

-> `label.quantity = Quantity`

-> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>)

-> `#label.quantity = Quantity`

that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to find a solution to the same problem, and came up with a solution which works for me. It is possible to have multiple files in the same package which specify comments, so I added another file called `Comments-properties.tmPreferences`, in the Java package with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.java-props</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string># </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>B25BCBF0-6483-11E2-BCFD-0800200C9A66</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Just for reference, the Java package directory is  `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/Java` on Mac

Comment: Just confirming this still works for ST3 (just go to `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/Java` instead). If the Java directory doesn't exist (as it didn't for me at the time), just create it.